# eficient elimination of old documens

Tags: arangodb

Using ArangoDB 3.6.x, I have a scenario with continuous documents coming into the database and the need to continuously eliminate old ones. What could be an efficient/simple algorithm to determine the documents to eliminate those records. Could I use the document "_key" for selection and elimination?

I guess that retrieving the documents from database to look at each of them would be a bad approach, so I'm trying to find an algorithm that might be simple, efficient. Ideally the database itself would provide such mechanism, like partitioning. f.ex. It wouldn't have to be very exact concerning data timestamps but it would have to be effective in the sense that I must assure that the total number of documents is kept under a maximum.

I'm specifically focusing on ArangoDB.

Thank you
João

Comment: I ended up using "TTL Indexes" and the results are quite good. https://www.arangodb.com/arangodb-training-center/ttl-indexes/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are qualifying "old" documents.  If these are by date, then you could simply make sure each document has a numeric timestamp attribute.  I use the AQL `DATE_NOW()` function or `(new Date()).valueOf()` in JavaScript.  Then, just add a [skiplist](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.6/indexing-skiplist.html) index on the timestamp attribute, allowing near instant sort and/or filter by numbers larger/smaller than `x`.

```
LET millisecondsAgo = (8 * 60 * 60 * 1000)  // 8 hours
FOR a IN collection_a
    FILTER a.timestamp < (DATE_NOW() - millisecondsAgo)
    REMOVE a IN collection_a
```

If "old" means something else, like "does this document exist in another collection", then your best bet is having a matching lookup key.  This could be the `_key` attribute or another, but it needs to be unique.  I use this to reconcile "existing" documents between collections:

```
FOR a IN collection_a
    FILTER LENGTH(
        FOR b IN collection_b
            FILTER b.uniqueKey == a.uniqueKey
            RETURN true
    ) == 0
    REMOVE a IN collection_a
```

There should be a [hash index](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.6/indexing-hash.html) (called "persistent index" in the UI, unique is good but not necessary) on both `collection_a` and `collection_b` on `uniqueKey`. Then, the `FOR b IN collection_b ...` query will match super quickly using the index, returning a `true` if something is found.  If no records are matched nothing is returned, so the returned array has a zero length.  Hash key lookups + calculating length of a very small array should be ***very*** fast.